# Initialization of application and splash-screen with progress bar (Swing)

Tags: java, swing, splash-screen

We have built a splash screen for our application. It works fine when the initialization of application is in the main thread, but when I move the initialization in EDT (SwingUtilities.invokeLater in main method), the progress bar and info label do not repaint itself due to blocking of EDT. I know, that using of invokeLater can help me to repaint the GUI. But my problem is: it's really hard to split the initialization of aplication in separate pieces (legacy code). And even if I do it, I will get a ugly matroshka-code (six times invokeLater in invokeLater).

Which solution should I prefer:

1. Leave initialization in main thread (my current decision)
2. Try to move it to EDT (if possible) and get matroshka code
3. Using Foxtrot lib to provide a non-blocking-sleep in EDT each time I update the splash screen (it works fine - the splash screen can repaint itself, but it's a hack for me)

Probably someone has a better solution?

P.S. I've already read some similar questions here but did not found anything helpful for me.

Comment: I don't see a reason to do the initialization on the `EDT`. Just make sure everything that concerns the `GUI` is done on the `EDT` but the rest can be done in another thread if needed.

Comment: use JWindow (required JFrame as parent) or undecorated JDialog, most common workaround before the SplashSceen was implemented in official API

Comment: @mKorbel Swing elements like progress bar or label cannot repaint itself due to blocked EDT.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau This is my problem. Lots of XML layout files are read and used on initialization. And I cannot get splitted GUI and non-GUI code. Currently we have no problems with initialization in main thread , but I'm not sure whether it will always work fine.

Comment: [Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to find the lowest hanging fruit. You have to construct GUI component models on the EDT, but you can load the data later used by a particular model on any thread.

Comment: @trashgod you are right. It would better to refactor our initialization code (and if I get time I will do it), but I've hoped to get a simple solution here.

Comment: The alternative is to use a `SwingWorker` to initialize model(s); it will take no less time, but the _perceived_ improvement in liveness may be acceptable.

Comment: @trashgod Bingo! Good Idea. Load XML file in doInBackground() and initialize the GUI in done(). I'm not sure whether I can refactor the code for this proposal, but it's realy good!

Answer (score 2):

Load the source data in the `doInBackground()` method of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), and `publish()` intermediate results; update the GUI component's model in `process()`. While data continues to load, initial results will be displayed and the GUI will function nominally. The *real* time to load data will remain unchanged, but the *perceived* time will be less.