# spinner image on JFrame while UI are creating

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingutilities

I have an application that after successfull login (on a `JFrame`), starts to create the main frame (class `MainUI` that extends from `JFrame`). That `MainUI` class contains a `JTabbedPane` (which each tab is a class that extends from `JPanel`) and, on `setVisible` method, creates and shows each tab.

I want to add on the login form, after successfull login, a *Spinner image* to indicate that the `MainUI` is being created.

After display the *Spinner image*, I invoke the creation of the `MainUI` and call the `setVisible` method on `EventQueue.invokeLater();` but the *Spinner image* is not updated. If I use `new Thread(runner).start();` is updated, but I get a lot of `Component creation must be done on Event Dispatch Thread`

Some code of Login.java:

```
buttonLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
       login();
   }
});

private void login()
{
   //check DB and permissions
   //if all is ok
   lMsj.setIcon(spinner);
   new Thread(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
          showMainUI(usr);
      }
   }).start();
}
private void showMainUI(final Usuario usr)
{
    Runnable runner = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            final MainUI mui = new MainUI();
            mui.setVisible(true);

            dispose();
        }
    };
    EventQueue.invokeLater(runner);
}
```

and some code of MainUI.java

```
public MainUI()
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1280, 960));

            createComponents();
        }
    });
}
private void initComponents()
{
   //..
   // menuItem = new ...
    // ...
}

@Override
public void setVisible(boolean value)
{
   //..
   if (Security.get().isAllowed("tab1")){
     addTab1();
   }
   //..
}

private void addTab1(){
   //..
   getTabbedPane().addTab("Tab1", new Tab1());
   //..
}
```

How I can fix this, so that the image is updated and the user interface is created in the "background"?

Comment: You have a problem.  Swing is not thread safe, which means you should never create or update the UI from outside the Event Dispatching Thread.  Instead, you should create the models/data that the views will rely on in a separate thread and then present the view and data within the EDT

Comment: `EventQueue.invokeLater` will execute the `Runnable` at some time in the future WITHIN the context of the EDT, where the spinner label is also operating, meaning that the two will be updated together...

Comment: I've already asked the same question. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912610/initialization-of-application-and-splash-screen-with-progress-bar-swing). There is no good solution for this problem, but probably some of possibilities (workarounds) in discussion will help you to solve your problem. Note: if you only need an animated splash screen, you can use the [standard approach](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/splashscreen.html) provided by Oracle